# Звук в web

Tags: html, аудио

Какой сейчас самый правильный способ заставить играть звук по клику по html-элементу?
Желательно чтобы работало у 99% пользователей.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не 99% конечно, но [audio](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_ref_av_dom.asp) хороший вариант. [Пример](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_av_met_play_pause) проигрывания по кнопке.

ЗЫ audio и video с точки зрения js не отличаются.

Answer (score 2):

Моё личное мнение, что если сайт не специализированный, как напр., Youtube, то звук - это зло. Но дело ваше. Попробуйте так:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    function playWave(sound) { 
        $("#wave").remove() 
        $('body').append("<embed id='wave' autostart='true' hidden='true' src='sound.wav' />");  // путь к звуковому файлу
     }

    $('.sound_link').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        playWave();
    });  
});
```

На кнопки/ссылки, где нужен звук, добавить класс **.sound_link**

Comment: Звук нужен для обучения иностранномму языку, так что не зло,
Нельзя написать на чистом html, или в этих функциях кроется какая-то настройка под возможности браузера?